# Projection into List Field using Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have a POJO something like this

```
Class BillEntity {
      private int id;
      private double amount;
      private List<Integer> paymentIds;
}
```

I want to fetch this Object from DB using Hibernate criteria, currently I am having code something like this

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Bill.class);
//some Join aliases, which are working as expected
criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.property("id") , "id")
        .add(Projections.property("amount") , "amount");

criteria.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(BillEntity.class));
criteria.list();
```

The `id` and `amount` are correctly populated, but I am unsure how `paymentIds` can be populated.

any pointers appreciated!